# Wifi and ethernet unstable (takes many tries to connect, disconnects)

Tags: networking, arch-linux, wifi, ethernet

Both my WiFi connection and my Ethernet connection have recently (I'd say about a week ago) become unstable, without any change in the configs.

Now in order to connect I've to try several times and it often randomly disconnects (this for the WiFi, I haven't been able to connect via Ethernet at all but I've tried much less often than connecting via WiFi).

I've already tried updating and changing the network manager app (tried wicd and NetworManager) without success. Anybody got any idea about how to fix this?

I'm on an update ArchLinux, asus k53

Comment: Any info in your `dmesg` log?

Comment: There is so much piece of information here that all you can do is to restart the wifi router and see if it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not much to go on here. I'll take pot shots. Do you have the right drivers for your hardware? Wifi and ethernet are two differant things. What exactly do you mean by unstable? Do you use dhcpcd for ethernet?

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network#Troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: sometimes when switching between wifi and ethernet (or back), it helps on my system to reset the corresponding service, as follows.

Switch to wifi:

```
sudo systemctl restart netctl-auto@wlp2s0.service
```

Switch to ethernet:

```
sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd@enp0s25.service
```